# Non-Jews reincarnating in Jews

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, soul, pinchas, reincarnation

I read in the name of (Ariz"l) some Kabbalistic books that [Zimri Ben Salu](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.25.14?lang=bi&with=Bamidbar%20Rabbah&lang2=en) was the reincarnation of [Shechem ben Chamor](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.34?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0) that took Dina and the story of Bnot Moav is [allegorically] a repetition of the story of Dina.

That seriously puzzled me, as I always understood that the Jewish souls come from a different repository altogether.

A different approach teaches that reincarnation aims a completion of one’s spiritual "tasklist" so to do that, theoretically, a person can reincarnate in a creature of a lower level (a gentile, an animal or e tree?) but not in higher ones.

How this phenomenon is explained?

---

(I would love to have the source also, please).

Comment: I heard Rabbi Yosef Mizrachi say that when Hashem went around and offered Torah to nations there was a small minority among the nations who wanted to accept the Torah but couldn't because the majority refused. Therefore, Hashem gives them an opportunity to convert in next lives

Comment: @DannySchoemann I agree that some topics are better to be left private, that's why I didn't ask about the details, but I don't think the whole idea of גלגול נשמות is purely Kabbalistic, in a way that it could only be discussed offline in private. Don't you agree?

Comment: "I always understood that the Jewish souls come from a different repository altogether" Can you source this? Without a source, the question is essentially "I think A, but I see a source saying Not A". The answer to that question would be "A is wrong, as seen in source that says Not A".

Comment: @Salmononius2 Your comment is very reasonable. But sometimes it's hard to boil decades of study to a single source. Moreover, as I stated, it contradicts the logic - how can a soul be reincarnated in something bigger than it was.

Comment: @AlBerko I am unclear as to what you are fully asking. Are you satisfied with the case of a Jew reincarnating as a Gentile, but only have a question about a Gentile reincarnating as a Jew; or do both bother you? Can you clarify in the question?

Comment: @DavidKenner I'm trying to understand the "logic" of reincarnation. If it is the completion of a full cycle I can understand "downgrading"  - a Jew reinc. in gentile or a tree on every cycle, but not "upgrading" a tree reincarnating as a person..

Comment: @AlBerko whats a full cycle? Why cant a full cycle start with rock/tree and move up to person; or start with person and move down to rock?